# Any search input / function on Google Slides?

Tags: google-slides

I am going to make **a lot of pages** inside the presentation.

And every page has a "Home" button.

I was wondering if there was any **search input or function** on Google Slides that I can insert on my "Home" page. Or is there any trick to allow **searching all pages of a presentation** within the presentation?

p.s., I'm using a mobile/tablet device while presenting.

Answer (score 1):

At this time, Google Slides doesn't include any search input or function that can be inserted on a slide but it's very likely that could be possible by using the recently announced [Google Slides API](https://developers.google.com/slides/).